# How can I link the column of a model to another using Django ForeignKey

Tags: django, forms, sqlite, model

I have the below models

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplierName = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    zone = models.IntegerField()
class Contact(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.SET("Company Deleted"), related_name="supplierC")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

On the html

```
<select name="supplier" id="supplier">
    <option value="1">Supplier 1</option>
    <option value="2">Supplier 2</option>
</select>
```

If I select supplier 1,and post the form to the view, I will have to first get the Supplier whose `id = 1`, then use the obtained query to fill the database for contact

```
def contactForm(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        supplier = Supplier.objects.get(pk=request.POST['supplier'])
        mydata ={}
        mydata['supplier'] = supplier
        mydata['name'] = request.POST['contact-name']
        new_contact = Contact(**mydata)
        new_contact.save()
```

Is there a way to avoid `supplier = Supplier.objects.get(pk=request.POST['supplier'])`

For instance in our model do something like `supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier.id, on_delete=models.SET("Company Deleted"),`

Where by in while creating the new record for Contact, we do directly as shown below

```
def contactForm(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        mydata ={}
        mydata['supplier'] = request.POST['supplier']
        mydata['name'] = request.POST['contact-name']
        new_contact = Contact(**mydata)
        new_contact.save()
```

Any help?

Comment: Use `mydata['supplier_id'] = request.POST['supplier']`. for a foreign key Django automatically creates a virtual field (with `_id` appended) which actually contains the related id. Although I would advice you to actually use a form class. See [Creating forms from models - Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#creating-forms-from-models)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `supplier_id` parameter to the `Contact` creation with the id value of the `Supplier` without having to query it from the database beforehand.

```
def contactForm(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        mydata ={}
        mydata['supplier_id'] = request.POST['supplier']
        mydata['name'] = request.POST['contact-name']
        new_contact = Contact(**mydata)
        new_contact.save()
```